# How to convert BeautifulSoup.ResultSet to string

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

So I parsed a html page with `.findAll` (BeautifulSoup) to variable named `result`.
If I type `result` in Python shell then press Enter, I see normal text as expected, but as I wanted to postprocess this result as string object, I noticed that `str(result)` returns garbage, like this sample:

```
\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x86\xd0\xb0</a><br />\n<hr />\n</div>
```

Html page source is `utf-8` encoded

How can I handle this?

---

Code is basically this, in case it matters:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.open(url).read())
result = soup.findAll(something)
```

Python is 2.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 2.6.7
BeautifulSoup.**version** 3.2.0

This worked for me:

```
unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,result))
```

I'm pretty sure a  `result` is a `BeautifulSoup.ResultSet` object, which seems to be an extension of the standard python list

Answer (score 3):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.open(url).read())
#findAll should get multiple parsed result
result = soup.findAll(something)
#then iterate result
for line in result:
    #get str value from each line,replace charset with utf-8 or other charset you need
    print line.__str__('charset')
```

BTW:BeautifulSoup's version is beautifulsoup-3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

That's not garbage, that's UTF-8-encoded text. [Use Unicode instead.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: it's commonly used term for describing character de/encoding problems, it's sure not garbage literally

Comment: But there is no problem. That's UTF-8-encoded text; you just don't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', p.decode()).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Unicode has [multiple normalization forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) 
That output should not be garbage. 
Use the `originalEncoding` attribute to verify the encoding scheme.
 Regarding python's unicode implementations, refer [this document](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html) (even for the normalization)

Comment: `soup.originalEncoding` returns `utf-8`. `result` which is BS.ResultSet object does not support this attributes. And I surely don't want to decode `utf-8` and encode to ASCII as I loose all foreign (to English) characters. I want `utf-8` string object out of this BS.ResultSet object

Comment: Have you tried going through the link given in @Ignacio's answer?