# Creating a program to store all the tweets off a page to be stored in a text file for analysis, however getting TypeErrors

Tags: python, tweepy

I have started off by including Tweepy and managed to get a program that is able to output a correct output with a search parameter, however, while trying to create a program that can save and store a person timeline for data analysis I came across a TypeError: must be str, not ResultSet.

```
import tweepy

#API keys access
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("", "")
client = tweepy.API(auth)

#Opening a file with the name of the user wanted
screen = input("Enter the screen name: ")
filename = (screen+".txt")
file = open(filename, "w")

#Getting the Users time line
user = client.get_user(screen_name=screen)
timeline = user.timeline()



#Writing new found data to the file. 
file.write(timeline)
file.close()
```

This code keeps on spitting out the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetTimeLine.py", line 20, in <module>
    file.write(timeline)
TypeError: must be str, not ResultSet
```

However for the set line:

```
file.write(timeline)
```

I add where I want it to become str through the user of

```
file.write(str(timeline))
```

Throwing out an entirely different error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GetTimeLine.py", line 20, in <module>
    file.write(str(timeline))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4122-4123: character maps to <undefined>
```

To try and fix this I tried to add .(encode"utf-8") however with no luck.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I searched for how to convert ResultSet to string and found this

```
unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,result))
```

Here "**result**" is your "**timeline**" variable, just put it and you will get it in string format. Doing simply str(timeline) will not encode it , that's why you are getting another error.

Just try it:) Cheers

Comment: Hi, tried this and it got me further than before, however now it comes up with a separate, NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined??

Comment: You are getting this error because you are running your code in python 3 . In python 3 unicode is replaced with str. So in code just put "str" instead of "unicode" .Like this str.join(u'\n',map(str,result)...and check this link also "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782772/how-to-convert-beautifulsoup-resultset-to-string"

Comment: Thank you for the reply I tried to add said code timeline=str.join(u'\n;,map(str,timeline)) however, this throws back the error of UniCodeEncodeError:  'charmap' can't encode characters in position xxxx-xxxx, it varies each time I run the code the two numbers? I have tried setting the output in the write line to file.write(str(timeline)) as well with little luck

Comment: Since completing this added extra, I managed to get further and download some peoples tweets and store their information, however, some pages don't work spitting out errors such as `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4b0' in position 1188: character maps to <undefined>`, however, some peoples accounts work and are able to be completed and kept,

Comment: Hi, I did some research on timeline() what it returns and all. If you can put data , what is inside timeline or just by printing or while debugging what you get exactly inside timeline. Just check what exactly you are getting, its a list or it's a dictionary .